# Autofac Collection Named and Non-Named Types

Tags: autofac

I'm using autofac and have a large amount of rules to resolve, they're being passed into specific validators, which use some common rules with some specific rules. Ninject had a .WhenInjectedInto property, and I understand that `.Named<T>("")` gives me similar functionality.. BUT

Given the following code:

Is it possible to have the IFooValidator's rules populated with Foo and FooBar.
And IBarValidator's rules populated with Bar and FooBar?

I have the following code:

```
public static class Dependencies
    {
        public static IContainer Configure()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IRule>();
            builder.RegisterType<Bar>().As<IRule>();

            builder.RegisterType<FooBar>().As<IRule>();

            builder.RegisterType<Foos>().As<IFooValidator>();
            builder.RegisterType<Bars>().As<IBarValidator>();

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }

    public interface IRule
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }

    public class Foo : IRule
    {
        public string Name { get { return "Foo"; }}
    }

    public class Bar : IRule
    {
        public string Name { get { return "Bar"; } }
    }

    public class FooBar : IRule
    {
        public string Name { get { return "FooBar"; } }
    }

    public interface IFooValidator
    {
        IList<IRule> Rules { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IBarValidator
    {
        IList<IRule> Rules { get; set; }
    }

    public class Foos : IFooValidator
    {
        public IList<IRule> Rules { get; set; }

        public Foos(IList<IRule> foo)
        {
            Rules = foo;
        }
    }

    public class Bars : IBarValidator
    {
        public IList<IRule> Rules { get; set; }

        public Bars(IList<IRule> bars)
        {
            Rules = bars;
        }
    }
```

I know it can be done using:

```
builder.Register<IFooValidator>(context =>
            {
                var foos = context.ResolveNamed<IList<IRule>>("Foo");
                var foobar = context.Resolve<IList<IRule>>();

                return new Foos(foos.Concat(foobar).ToList());

            });
```

but it feels messy, is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've settled with:

```
            builder.RegisterType<Foo>().Named<IRule>("Foo");
            builder.RegisterType<Bar>().Named<IRule>("Bar");

            builder.RegisterType<FooBar>()
                .As<IRule>()
                .Named<IRule>("Foo")
                .Named<IRule>("Bar");

            builder.RegisterType<Foos>().As<IFooValidator>().WithParameter((info, context) => info.Name == "foo", (info, context) => context.ResolveNamed<IList<IRule>>("Foo"));
```

If anyone can provide a better answer please do and I'll be happy to mark it.

**UPDATE**

After thinking a bit more on the problem, It didn't really make sense to be injecting dependencies like this. Since a change would've required a rebuild anyway. I decided to refactor this part of the application to use composition and inheritance rather than aggregation and DI